# Office.js throws exception when tried to read cell address if Excel is kep Open for 20-30 min and then try to read- its random

Tags: office-js

using office.js i am trying to read the cell value by passing the address of cell to a function. it works all fine but sometime it just throws exception and exception messages are too general that you do not know what the issue is.

look at the function below its all good but some time i get error when ctx is tried to sync  at  return `ctx.sync().then(function () {`

```
public getDataAtRange(rangeAddress: string): JQueryPromise<any[]> {
        let defer = $.Deferred();

        if (rangeAddress !== null) {
            Excel.run(function (ctx: Excel.RequestContext) {
                let range = rangeAddress.split("!");
                let sheet = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getItem(range[0]);
                let selectedRange = sheet.getRange(rangeAddress);
                selectedRange.load(["values", "text"]);

                return ctx.sync().then(function () {
                    let data: any[] = [];
                    for (let i = 0; i < selectedRange.text.length; i++) {
                        for (let j = 0; j < selectedRange.text[i].length; j++) {
                            let text = (selectedRange.text[i][j]).trim();
                            let value = selectedRange.values[i][j];
                            if (text !== "") {
                                let cellValue: any = { value: "", text: "" };
                                cellValue.value = value;
                                cellValue.text = text;
                                data.push(cellValue);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    defer.resolve(data);
                });
            }).catch(function (error: any) {
                console.log("Error in getDataAtRange(): " + error);
                if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
                    console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
                }
                defer.reject("Error in reading cell value, make sure the selected cell is not in Edit mode.");
            });
        } else { defer.resolve(); }

        return defer.promise();
    }
```

Office.js library is very buggy, there is no proper error or exception all exception it will say is general error

**If Excel is kept open for sometime say 20-30 min, and then try to read the data, it throws this exception**

Answer (score 1):

Office.js is certainly an evolving platform, and the entirety of the Excel & Word APIs under the `Excel` and `Word` namespaces are just a year old (with many APIs that are even more recent).  Still, I don't know if I would describe it as "very buggy" -- and at least in terms of Excel, which is where my expertise and primary focus is, I actually think we have a pretty solid foundation...

Likewise, our exceptions *do* try to be specific whenever we can (we probably have a couple dozen different exception types), and we'll append a ".debugInfo" object to many of the exceptions, when we can provide additional information (i.e., location of failure).

Getting back to your question: the code you provided looks reasonable, and is quite similar to what we have in some of our samples.  Can you clarify what is the exact error message you're getting, and what the debugInfo contains?  Can you show what the input is?

If the error feels truly random, there are two things I can think of that might be causing it:

1) The user enters edit mode.  We will quit processing as soon as the user does that (an Excel limitation).  I am not sure what error we produce when this happens, though I'll follow up on this on my end.  There's a good chance we could be more descriptive in that error.

2) You are creating a large number (~50) of simultaneous requests (i.e., independent `Excel.run`-s).  Again, it might well be that we need a better error message (I'll follow up on that too), but if I had to guess just by looking at your code, this seems like the most likely cause.

Comment: i feel its buggy because even very simple issues are not been identified or fixed for eg. look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39455625/office-addin-doesnt-occupy-all-the-space-scrollbar-is-missing-when-office-toolb?noredirect=1#comment66273933_39455625 its a first spot on issue how can nobody thought about it.

Comment: We use it and it's not buggy for us. Not well documented with examples? Probably, but things are improving as we speak. Every week there is something new. Sorry, @shyam_ not to agree with you!

Comment: hi Michael, i think i can reproduce the error now, if you keep excel for long time idle, say 20-30 min and then come back and try reading it. it throws this error. can you please guide me on this how to fix it.